# Are Isopropyl Alcohol (2-Propanol) and 1-Propanol tautomers?

Tags: organic-chemistry, cis-trans-isomerism, tautomer

They both are structural isomers, but are they tautomers too?

Comment: First, how do you define "tautomer"?

Answer (score 0):

Tautomers need to be able to interconvert readily and quickly. This is done via proton transfer. For example in keto-enol tautomerism (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keto%E2%80%93enol_tautomerism#/media/File:Keto-Enol-Tautomerie.png) the proton on the alpha carbon donates its electrons to form a pi bond between the 2 carbons. As a result the pi bond between the carbonyl carbon and oxygen breaks and the now negatively charged oxygen picks up the proton which was originally lost.

In propan-1-ol and propan-2-ol, the oxygens are on different atoms and there is no way they can interconvert, so they are not tautomers.